# Idiomatic way to access properties of union type

Tags: flowtype, union-types

What is the idiomatic way to access properties of union type that may be missing in one of the types merged in the union?

```
type DataColumn = {
  value: number;
};

type CalculatedColumn = {
  calculation: string;
};

type Column = DataColumn | CalculatedColumn;

function getValue(c: Column) {
  return c.value || c.calculation;
}
```

Flow [typecheck](https://flowtype.org/try/#0FAFwngDgpgBAIgQxAgwgewDYFcC2A7GAXhgG9gYYA3BbKALhj1wCMoAnAbmAF8vRJYKGgGMsGJFAAm6bPiKlyMYSLFIAlmjwMAziDZq8Acy69g-aDBm4CxRMityAPpZXiQUh3j4AzLHmEgGgRQABQAlAoUIAAWbGgA7oxQiQCibHFsIQDk3mhoWWEmZr7+gZowhlAgAGo0WKHCDJ4RZBRsVVhsBMIAdNS0MI7OvcoYom5BMAD0U4POoYU8ZpU1daEk-fUMAIwATADM3IsrtbQhJKPj6poMOXlZR1xAA) results in the following error:

```
13:   return c.value || c.calculation;
                          ^ property `calculation`. Property not found in
13:   return c.value || c.calculation;
                        ^ object type
```

[@dfkaye](https://twitter.com/dfkaye/status/803503774677352448) pointed out on twitter that if there is an error thrown for the "default" case, it works:

```
function e() {
  throw new Error('foo');
}

function getValue(c: Column) {
  return c.value || c.calculation || e();
}
```

Can somebody explain:

1. Why it works? Is it intentional, or a side effect?
2. Why is it necessary? Column type has always either `value` or `calculation`, so error case should never happen.
3. Is there a better, more idiomatic way?
4. Is this a safe approach, or is it likely to break in future?

PS: Seems like in TypeScript [it can be done](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0D%0Atype%20DataColumn%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20value%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20CalculatedColumn%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20calculation%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Column%20%3D%20DataColumn%20%7C%20CalculatedColumn%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20getValue(c%3A%20Column)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20(%3CDataColumn%3Ec).value%20%7C%7C%20(%3CCalculatedColumn%3Ec).calculation%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AgetValue(%7Bvalue%3A%20123%7D)%3B%0D%0AgetValue(%7Bcalculation%3A%20'foo'%7D)%3B%0D%0A) using type assertions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why it works? Is it intentional, or a side effect?

It's most likely a bug, Flow simple ignores all branches but last:

```
function getValue(c: Column) {
  return c.value || c.calculation || undefined;
}
```

> Why is it necessary? Column type has always either value or calculation, so error case should never happen

This is where you are wrong. If value has a type `{ value: number }` it means that it can have any other property of any type, including `calculation` of type `string` or may be of some other type.

> Is there a better, more idiomatic way?

Yes, see Nat Mote's answer

> Is this a safe approach, or is it likely to break in future?

It's not safe in principle, so it's very likely to break in the future

> Seems like in TypeScript it can be done using type assertions.

You can do the same thing in Flow, but it's unsafe:

```
function getValue(c: Column) {
  return ((c: any): DataColumn).value || ((c: any): CalculatedColumn).calculation;
}
```

Also you should not forget that numbers and string can be falsey.

Answer (score 4):

The idiomatic way is to use [disjoint unions](https://flowtype.org/blog/2015/07/03/Disjoint-Unions.html). This passes with no errors:

```
type DataColumn = {
  kind: 'data';
  value: number;
};

type CalculatedColumn = {
  kind: 'calculated';
  calculation: string;
};

type Column = DataColumn | CalculatedColumn;

function e() {
  throw new Error('foo');
}

function getValue(c: Column) {
  return c.kind === 'data' ? c.value : c.calculation;
}

getValue({kind: 'data', value: 123});
getValue({kind: 'calculated', calculation: 'foo'});
```

I'm not actually sure why the case you described doesn't work. I can't think of any reason it would be unsound. But disjoint unions definitely work.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to modify the data (at least, not yet).